# Layered Navigation for Admin Report

Tags: category, backend, layered-navigation, reports

this is a rather custom request.

**Is it possible to use the layered navigation (attribute filter for products) for backend reports and if yes: how?**

I need this for a custom report site. I managed to add a site with grid layout and wire it to a custom database table, link it with the products and display the information needed. Also filtering for the known attributes works.

Problem is: I do not know which and how many attributes will appear in the future. I could add a column to the grid each time a new attribute is defined, but that way the grid will get very long over time an thus will be rendered unsusable. Another problem are multiselect attributes.

Same goes for categories, since a product can appear in several categories the row for that product would have to appear multiple times in the grid.

I already tried to add the block for the layered navigation to my report site without success uo to now. Also I have searched for that topic for quite a while now without result.

Where should I start looking? Anyone had a similar requirement? Maybe anyone even has a solution?

Comment: Putting on hold given lack of interest. If you solved this it would be great to get an update.

Comment: Hey benmarks, I did not manage to solve this inside the backend. Instead I've done the custom report page in the frontend. I'm using a customer group, so that only limited peoble can reach and see that report page. The page itself is a modified catalog-page, that way the use of the layered navigation and category browsing are already there to be used. But for the request itself: I'm still interested in a solution.